# npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data ,error in creating npm light-server

Tags: node.js, lite-server

I was trying to run npm lite server ,but it is showing me "Failed to parse json data ,
I initiated the process with `npm init` command then I gave the command `npm install lite-server --save-dev` and it created the node module .after that I updated the script section as :

```
 "scripts": {
    "start":"npm run lite"
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    "lite":"lite-server"
  },
```

After that I gave the command `npm start` but then it creates an error Failed to parse json data which I do not know how to resolve .
Following is the error log  :

```
    0 verbose cli [
    0 verbose cli   '/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node',
    0 verbose cli   '/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/npm',
    0 verbose cli   'start'
    0 verbose cli ]
    1 info using npm@8.3.1
    2 info using node@v16.14.0
    3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
    4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
    5 timing config:load:file:/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 1ms
    6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
    7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
    8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
    9 timing config:load:file:/home/admin/Desktop/test_git/.npmrc Completed in 7ms
    10 timing config:load:project Completed in 10ms
    11 timing config:load:file:/home/admin/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
    12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
    13 timing config:load:file:/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
    14 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
    15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
    16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
    17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
    18 timing config:load Completed in 19ms
    19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 21ms
    20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
    21 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
    22 timing npm:load:display Completed in 5ms
    23 verbose logfile /home/admin/.npm/_logs/2022-06-18T13_06_09_781Z-debug-0.log
    24 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 6ms
    25 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
    26 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
    27 timing npm:load Completed in 32ms
    28 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
    29 timing command:run-script Completed in 6ms
    30 timing command:start Completed in 8ms
    31 verbose stack JSONParseError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 4006 while parsing '{
    31 verbose stack   "name": "test_git",
    31 verbose stack   "version": "1.'
    31 verbose stack     at /home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json-fast/index.js:11:61
    31 verbose stack     at async RunScript.run (/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/run-script.js:75:19)
    31 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:66:5)
    32 verbose cwd /home/admin/Desktop/test_git
    33 verbose Linux 4.15.0-187-generic
    34 verbose argv "/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node" "/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/npm" "start"
    35 verbose node v16.14.0
    36 verbose npm  v8.3.1
    37 error code EJSONPARSE
    38 error path /home/admin/Desktop/test_git/package.json
    39 error JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 4006 while parsing '{
    39 error JSON.parse   "name": "test_git",
    39 error JSON.parse   "version": "1.'
    40 error JSON.parse Failed to parse JSON data.
    40 error JSON.parse Note: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
    41 verbose exit 1
    42 timing npm Completed in 205ms
    43 verbose code 1
    44 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
    44 error     /home/admin/.npm/_logs/2022-06-18T13_06_09_781Z-debug-0.log
```

So can someone please suggest how to resolve this issue ,thank you!

Comment: Put your package.json file in a JSON [validator](https://jsonlint.com/) to see the errors. One issue is your each script commands should end with a `,`

Answer (score 0):

There should a comma `,` between every instruction in script section .

So the script section should be updated as :

```
"scripts": {
    "start":"npm run lite" ,
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" ,
    "lite":"lite-server"
  },
```